# Integrating Tally in Swing Application

Tags: java, swing, jakarta-ee

I am going to develop a Desktop application using Swing and Spring, Hibernate.
My application will take input from user and end of the day that all entries should enter into Tally. So my question is it possible to do, If yes can any one please provide the link that explain how to do that...?

Comment: *"..should enter into Tally."*  What is 'Tally'?

Comment: Probably a POS system or banking system's tally....

Comment: Yes it is possible. No I can't provide a link.

Comment: @esej thanks but can you tell me how to do it not about codding just tell what should i use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered going through Tally's [integration capabilities documentation](http://www.tallysolutions.com/website/html/tallydeveloper/integration-capabilities.php)? It quite clearly states that they have an XML based API that supports HTTP Get and Post requests.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for this, if my English is wrong please forgive me, my intention is only to provide more information to all. So those who are looking for same please first go through with [Tally-doc](http://mirror.tallysolutions.com/Downloads/TDL%20Developer/Tally.ERP%209%20-%20Integration%20Capabilities.pdf)

then read this [document](http://mirror.tallysolutions.com/Downloads/TDL%20Developer/Tally.ERP%209%20-%20Integration%20Capabilities.pdf) You will understand more quickly. Best luck.

Answer (score 0):

See also
https://sourceforge.net/projects/vch2tally/
If you can call dll from java it makes export of data easy.
Of course the tool is developed from the documentation 'Tally integration Captivities'.